# Remove Escape character from object or string in c#?

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, stringify

I am passing string, through ajax, to action method in mvc,
Below is my ajax call

```
                $("#btnEncrypt").click(function () {
                var pay = JSON.stringify({
                  'payload': {"exp":1442515543,"method":"Login"},
                  'secretKey': "123456"
                });             

                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",                    
                url: '@Url.RouteUrl("GetData")',                   
                data: pay,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {                        
                    alert("Success");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('error');
                }
                });
                });
```

Below is my Action method(Generate) in which I had pass two parameters

```
                [HttpPost]
                public ActionResult Generate(string payload, string secretKey)
                {
                 Here I am getting payload as "{\"exp\":1442515543,\"method\":\"Login\"}" 
                 instead of "{"exp":1442515543,"method":"Login"}"
                }
```

So, how can I get original request that I am passing through ajax call

```
    "{"exp":1442515543,"method":"Login"}"
```

in action method without escaping character?  Thank you in advance :)

Note : 
1) I had tried without stringify for request parameter, but it's not worked.
2) Here parameters(exp and method) vary according to different request and I had around 200 request which all are using different paramters.

Comment: do you know that `"{\"exp\":1442515543,\"method\":\"Login\"}"` equals to `"{"exp":1442515543,"method":"Login"}"` in runtime? i did not get whats wrong

Comment: Are you sure those escapes are in the actual string and not just in the debugger view?

Comment: `payload` should be a model containing properties `exp` and `method`, not a `string` (and better, include a property for `secretKey` so you only have one parameter).

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I had check that string in Watch(Name : Value) and result is same with escape character.

Comment: @StephenMuecke It should be better if payload is model,but here my payload is vary according to request so I am not able to create one model and define this properties.

Comment: @Hrdk You can create `payload` model class (include your properties in that) and get value as `payload` object as `Generate(Payload payload, string secretKey)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here just need to Deserialize the payload at Action to remove escape charactor

```
var obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(payload,targetType:null);
```

Problem solved :)

Answer (score 1):

1) Build a PayloadDto c# object

With exp and method properties and then in your method definition :

```
public ActionResult Generate(PayloadDto payload, string secretKey)
```

2) Build a PayDto c# object

Build a PayDto that agreggates the PayloadDto and the secretKey string.

```
public ActionResult Generate(PayDto pay)
```

Comment: dynamic obj =  Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{\"exp\":1442515543,\"method\":\"Login\"}");

your string is ok : 
obj.exp.Value =>  1442515543
obj.method.Value => "Login"

Comment: Using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject I get dynamic value thats working, and fine, But now how to pass that dynamic value to this my main function public static string Encode(object payload) ? now I am getting [
  [
    []
  ],
  [
    []
  ]

Comment: @Hrdk you can't just use `object` and hope it will work out which object type to use. Create an object with the appropriate properties and use that, as shown in this answer. Nothing dynamic needed

Comment: @Basic But here I can not create object with proerties because I had around 200 request with different properties(parameter).

Comment: You need to abstract your problem a bit more :)
Consider finding a more generic way to solve your problem or expose your real problem in a different post so we can help you out.

Comment: @christophe.chapron Is there anything else that we can do to remove escape character in C#? I have found some answers but that are for ruby (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532527/remove-back-slash-in-string) and php (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659708/remove-escape-character-from-jquery-post)

Comment: your json string received is correct so you need to deserialize it : either with newtonsoft.json or with the native JavaScriptSerializer:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx